# Python appending multiple returned files into one file

Tags: python, file, append

I would like to be able to take my multiple returned files, which are all of the same structure in .csv format, into one file. Below I have posted the part of the code that I'm referring to.

I am not sure if I should use .write or .append to achieve this efficiently.

```
for thisfile in files:
    if re.match(pattern, thisfile):

s3.download_file(Bucket=os.environ.get('SP_BUCKET'), Key=thisfile)

return files
```

---

```
append files here
```

Lets call the file names part-1 part-2 and part-3. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to write files? Also, please format your code, as for now it will result in an indentation error.

Comment: Yes I do know how to write files. Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: You wrote you want to put them into one file, so what's the problem if you know how to write files?

Comment: I'm asking you if that's the best way to do it.

Comment: I want to be able to open all files and concatenate them with a statement. Also, I don't know the exact naming conventions, I have a regexp pattern to do describe them.